# What would happen to a misinstalled globe valve?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, piping

Since globe valves are unidirectional and should be installed in one direction only I encountered a valves supplier that does not mark the globe valve body with flow direction, the valve eventually got welded (socket weld ends, not flanged) in a by-pass branch on a skid.

What might go wrong if the valve is installed incorrectly? Is there any way to check this other than the flow direction on the body (in the as-built situation)?  (the body is symmetrical for both inlet and outlet sides).

Comment: Isn't the primary issue with a globe value that you want the screw mechanism to be on the low-pressure (outlet) side when the valve is closed? So if it is installed backward, you can't do things like service the packing on the valve stem without taking the system out of service altogether. Even if the valve isn't labeled, can't you see into the openings well enough to see which side has the mechanism?

Answer (score 1):

Globe valves are installed in such a direction that the pressure side is under the disc to protect the packing from pressure in the off position. If installed backward the pressure will be on the top side and this reduces ability to throttle the valve at near closed position. Maintenance of spindle gland cannot be done in this orientation and there is more chance of leaks developing due to pressure on the packing which cannot be serviced as well.
To check the direction of installation you can take help of embossed orientation arrow,if the valve is of asymmetrical construction the end under the disc is the inlet, if the valve is of symmetrical make and you have already installed it you cannot peer into it to observe which end has the mechanism you might have to settle for identifying the end by using the vendor drawings and direction of rotation of hand wheel as a reference (CW or CCW)